# Algorithms to learn 3D model from series of photos

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

Can you point me to the papers/books on this topic?

I saw Adobe AfterEffects CS5 demonstrating such feature. It should also be implemented in some robotic systems which auto-discover the environment around and there place in it.

However I can't find so far any introductory material. Help?..

Comment: Start here http://www.amazon.com/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518

Comment: One process for this is described in "Rapid Scene Reconstruction on Mobile Phones from Panoramic Images" by Pan, *et al*: http://www.edwardrosten.com/work/pan_2011_rapid.pdf

Answer (score 1):

3D scanning is probably the google-fodder you want to start with.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_scanner) has a lot of info.  There are a number of papers listed there, though I cannot give any quality assessments.

There are some fairly accessible [techniques](http://hackaday.com/2012/04/27/scanning-turntable-digitizes-objects-as-3d-models/) that just rely on lazy susan and cheap cameras.

Answer (score 1):

In highly controlled scenarios, where you can control the camera, lighting, and object position, it's doable with methods like the "fairly accessible techniques" in Tom Kerr's answer.

With a robot that can move around, but not control lighting or object positions, it's much more complex but often doable.  It's an active field of research.

In the most general case, when you have a fixed series of photos with arbitrary angles and lighting, it's extremely difficult.